# Rails ActiveRecord: how to get non-duplicate child records by super-parent in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have four tables called `Albums`, `Songs`, `Singers` and `SongSingers`.

```
Albums { Id, Name } 
Songs { Id, AlbumId, Name }
Singers { Id, Name }
SongSingers { Id, SongId, SingerId }
```

- Album has many songs.
- Song belongs to an Album.
- SongSinger belongs to Song and Singer.
- Song and Singer have many SongSingers.

Each song may have same or different singers.

In View, how can I get all non-duplicate Singers by AlbumId.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Absolutely no problem.

1. You are querying for singers. That's what the query will start with.
2. You have a condition on songs stored in association. We'll need it soon.

   ```
   @album.songs
   ```
3. Join songs and singers so you can apply the above condition. Note: you're still selecting singers! It's just that now you can place conditions on their songs.

   ```
   Singer.joins(:songs)
   ```
4. Now apply it:

   ```
   Singer.joins(:songs).merge(@album.songs)
   # It's pretty much the same as this, but more concise:
   Singer.joins(:songs).merge(songs: {album_id: @album.id})
   ```
5. Now filter down duplicates:

   ```
   Singer.joins(:songs).merge(@album.songs).uniq
   ```

#### Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :songs
  has_many :song_singers, :through => :songs
  has_many :singers,      :through => :song_singers

  ...

end
```

In the view, you can now simply call this

```
@album.singers.uniq
```