# Concatenating multiple ActiveRecord child arrays into one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two models:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
end
```

I'm looking up location as follows:

```
locations = Locations.find_by(city: "Orlando")
```

Is it possible to concatenate all products into one array while weeding out all duplicate product_ids (and not necessarily worrying about what location it originally belonged to)?

Comment: Well, you can solve it using [a `joins`/`merge` combo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544385/rails-activerecord-how-to-get-non-duplicate-child-records-by-super-parent-in-vi/30544680#30544680), only bearing in mind that product's association is named `location`, not `locations`. I'm not sure it's a duplicate, but it's pretty close.

Comment: Why would the id in products have duplicates?

Comment: Multiple locations have the same products.  Best Buy has the same Sony Television is an example.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are only returning a single location. Did you mean `Location.where(city: "Orlando")` instead? Assuming you did I would consider doing this:

```
location_ids = Location.where(city: "Orlando").pluck(:id)
products = Product.where(location_id: location_ids)
```

You could also do it using a join:

```
products = Product.joins(:location).where(location: {city: "Orlando"})
```

Or if you want the location available later, switch `joins` to `includes`.